# PHP : Post routes not working, 404 not found

Tags: php, post, slim

I'm using Slim framework. I've made an API with Post routes and Get routes
The Get ones are working perfectly
The Post ones are not.

this one is working when accessed via javascript or php

```
 $app->get('/test',function(){
 });
```

While this one return an error 404 not found when accessed

```
 $app->post('/testpost',function(){
 });
```

I can't figure out the problem
thank you for your help

Comment: $app->post('/testpost',function() use($app){
 }); for both get and post request

Comment: Have you set proper htaccess rules?

Comment: @bub if it wasn't set up correctly, it wouldn't be working for `get()` either

Answer (score 0):

Read the [docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#get-route).

> ### POST Route
>
> You can add a route that handles only POST HTTP requests with the Slim application’s `post()` method. It accepts two arguments:
>
> - The route pattern (with optional named placeholders)
> - **The route callback**

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->post('/books', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // Create new book
});
```

If you are posting your data and don't see it, that's because you're not passing any `$request` parameter to the callback.

The Slim's router is based on [nikic/FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute), so if you prefer you may also refer to its docs to better understand it.

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing?

Start up the PHP built in web server via `php -S`

and then I recommend using Curl:

```
curl -v -X POST http://localhost:8080/testform
```